# Probability of ordered events

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are iid uniform over $(0,1)$. I want to evaluate $P(X_1 > X_2 > X_3)$

### Thoughts.

I try to solve this using geometric argument since the joint of the $X_i$ is uniform over the unit cube. I see by graphing that the  region bounded by $x_1 > x_2 > x_3$ on the first octant is a tetrahedron of side $\sqrt{2}$  so its volume is $ \frac{\sqrt{2}^2}{6 \sqrt{2}}  = \frac{1}{3} $ so that probability is just $vol(tetrahedron)/volume(cube) = \boxed{\frac{1}{3}} $.

Now, how can we solve this analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be any permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$ and define $X_\sigma=(X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<X_{\sigma(3)})$. We are looking for $P(X_{id})$. By symmetry, $P(X_\sigma)$ does not depend on $\sigma$ and

$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_3} P(X_\sigma)=1$$

(where $S_3$ is the group of permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$). Since $S_3$ has $3!=6$ elements, we obtain that $P(X_\sigma)=\frac{1}{6}$.

---

Other method: since the joint distribution is uniform on the cube $C=[0,1]^3$, the probability you are looking for is

$$P(X_1<X_2<X_3) = \int_C 1_{\{x<y<z\}}\; dV $$

Since $\left\{ x\in C\; \middle|\;  x<y<z \right\}= \{ 0\leqslant x\leqslant 1,\; x<y\leqslant 1,\; y<z\leqslant 1  \}$, we obtain

$$P(X_1<X_2<X_3)= \int_0^1 \int_x^1 \int_y^1 1\; dz\; dy\; dx$$

which can be evaluated to $\frac{1}{6}$.

*Note*: you made a mistake in your computation of the volume of the tetrahedron.

Comment: I dont understand how you got your bounds in the second method? May you elaborate a little bit? Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

The volume of the tetrahedron is 1/3 baseArea times height, which in this case is $1/3\cdot 1/2 \cdot 1=1/6$.

You could integrate 
$$\int_{x_1=0}^1\int_{x_2=x_1}^1\int_{x_3=x_2}^1 1 \, dx_3\,dx_2\,dx_1=1/6.$$

You could also recognize that there are 6 equally likely orderings of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$.